# How do you install MongoDB 5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 with apt-get?

Tags: apt, 20.04, mongodb

I'm wondering how to install the latest MongoDB version 5.0 via apt-get to avoid having to spend time on the mongodb official website and enter any personal information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the mongo pgp key:

`curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

2. Add the mongodb source list

`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list`

3. Run update to update local sources list

`sudo apt update`

4. Install the mongodb package

`sudo apt install mongodb-org`

5. Start the mongodb servicde

`sudo systemctl start mongod.service`

6. Verify the service is running

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

7. Configure mongodb to start on startup

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

8. Verify the mongo shell is installed and that you can connect to your local mongodb instance

`mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'`

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04-source

Modified versions from 4.4 to 5.0.